# Embed Google Form in Gmail using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, html-email, google-forms

I'm trying to use Apps script to embed a prefilled Form in an email.  The emails will only be sent to Gmail users.  I want something that works the same as pressing the 'include form in email' option when manually emailing a form.

I've successfully created the `prefilledUrl` and used `UrlFetchApp` and `HtmlService` to get the Html from the form and send email.

But when it arrives it looks like the screenshot below and user can not submit.
[image: Screenshot of form embedded in email]

A stripped down version of the  code I am using is the following:

```
var prefilledForm = 'prefilledForm link here');
Logger.log(prefilledForm);

var subject = 'Message from Office';
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(prefilledForm);
var htmlBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(response).getContent();

var body = 'Dear '+mName+',\n\n'+mMessage+'\nPlease acknowledge by submitting the form below.\nRegards,\nSchool Office';

GmailApp.sendEmail(eEmail,subject,body,{
  noReply:true,
  htmlBody: htmlBody
});
```

Is there anyway to embed the form in an email just like it does when you select 'include form in email' like the screenshot below?

[image]

Comment: Apologies, I just noted that the two screenshots show different forms. But the point still stands that the one sent by Google is formatted better than the first one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Send the form to yourself with the form included in the email.
2. Open Gmail in the browser, press F12. Find the div of the form in the email body.
   [image]
3. Paste the div code to the body of the Apps Script HTML file. Or paste it to email HTML body in your script, I didn't test it.
   [image]
4. Send the email with the above HTML file, you should be able to get a similar result as below.
   [image]

Comment: Very interesting solution! I tried it and it seemed to work.  It there anything in the copied element that could interfere with normal functionality, like the 'draftResponse' hidden input?

Comment: I didn't see anything abnormal with the copied element, it's the same as the email sent from the Form. I also made a video for this solution.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QzzoL1hg8n8

Comment: Thanks, I can think of several uses for this solution already.  Unfortunately, the original posting requires the form to be created programmatically which may cause a problem as I will be unable to send each form to myself and retrieve the div.  This is a great start though and it may be possible to adapt to my needs.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I found workaround to allow to do it without need of manual attention. After point 3rd in Ashton Fei's response replace all instances of Title, description and link url with desired values using getCode() and replace():

```
  var formUrl = form.getPublishedUrl()
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("form.html").getCode(); // HTML code to string
  template = template.replaceAll("FORM__URL", formUrl).replace("TITLE", title).replace("Descpition_text", desctiptionText); //Swapping bits that need change
  var htmlBody = eval(template).getContent() //"Go back to HTML"
```

Now you can use this HTML as you email htmlBody

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work for me:

1. email the form embedded to yourself
2. Click "Forward" and modify the email the way you want it (you can remove and add things like logo, etc.)
3. Click "Save as a template" and give it a name (make email "Full Screen" and click on the three dots in the lower righthand corner)

When you want to send it to a client, click "compose" (full screen), maximize the email window, click on the three dots (explained above)and chose the template you created.