# Embed google form within an Email programmatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I can use FormsApp to create a google form. Is there a way to embed that form in an e-mail automatically? Currently I can click on include in an e-mail through user interface and click on send. Is there a way to do this through Google Scripts?

Comment: Check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53417504/embed-google-form-in-gmail-using-apps-script/54664344